# Latest changes are not reflecting in azure app service for react app using GitHub actions

Tags: reactjs, azure, caching, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am using the basic default configuration in the azure app service and there are no warning and errors while building.

The Deployment is also succeeded but the latest changes are not showing in the production, still showing the previous build.

This is script am using for pushing the build into azure app service

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - AppName

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - stage
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build
        run: |
          npm install
          CI=false npm run build-stage

      - name: Create zip archive
        run: zip -r node-app.zip .

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: node-app.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'AppName'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ My profile key }}
          package: .
```

- I have cleared the cache in the browser and also tried it in incognito mode.
- Restarted the app service

Answer (score 0):

After you make any changes locally make sure you push the changes to your Github repository with the commands below:-

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin "git repository link"
git push -u origin main -f

#Now after making some changes in your local code or file you can add git add "file-name" or git add . to add entire directory again. 

git init
git add "file-name"
git commit -m "second commit"
git branch -M main
#Check for the remote git repository URL
git remote -v
 
#Push the changes 
git push -u origin main -f
```

After pushing the changes in the Repository, ***You can click on `Sync button` in the Deployment Center to run the Workflow again like below:-***

[image]

[image]

You can also **re-run** the Deployment from your **Github Actions tab** like below:-

[image]

Refer my **[SO thread answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419541/how-to-solve-azure-web-app-deployment-unauthorized-code-401/76421703#)** to **Deploy React app successfully via Github actions**.