# I'm trying to deploy a project to azure through git but I'm getting an error

Tags: python, git, azure, requirements.txt

Here's the error...
[image]

I have a requirements.txt file in the main project folder. Any help would be appreciated!

[GitHub Repository link of the project](https://github.com/treebush/OMS)

I tried moving the file around different sub folders and pushing to git before trying to deploy again but no luck. Also, I have no idea what I'm doing so that's a problem :(

Comment: Its also saying I should update my pip version but on my terminal it says its the current version. I failed to set up a virtual environment when I installed a bunch of stuff so I might have conflicts or something. Haven't figured out how to fix that yet.

Comment: Please provide your github repository link if you don't have any sensitive information.

Comment: Nothing sensitive, basically empty. Just testing.

Comment: https://github.com/treebush/OMS

Answer (score 0):

***I could run [your project](https://github.com/treebush/OMS) locally and deploy to Azure App Service.***

**Steps followed:**

- Cloned project to my local environment and pushed it to my GitHub repository.
- Create and activate virtual environment with below commands:

```py
py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

Run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the required dependencies:

[image]

Run `python manage.py migrate`:

[image]

Run `python migrate.py runserver`:

[image]

**Response 1:**

[image]

**Response 2:**

[image]

Project structure in GitHub:
[image]

**Deploying to Azure using GitHub Actions:**

- Created `Python 3.10 Azure App Service` :

[image]

- Configured **Deployment** while creation of App Service:

[image]

- Once the App Service gets created, the deployment process will be started, and it can be tracked in `GitHub Actions`.
- Workflow to deploy the application will be created automatically:

**My Workflow:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - <web_app_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: '<web_app_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_XXXXXXX }}
```

- **Deployment succeeded:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting all of this! I tried the whole process again. It made it through build but now is posting this error in deployment.......

deploy
Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
deploy
Deployment Failed, Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Unauthorized (CODE: 401)

Comment: I tried fixes on this comment thread but wasn't successful, any ideas? ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511599/unable-to-deploy-to-azure-web-app-services

Comment: .....https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10181

Comment: Check if `Basic Auth` [option](https://i.imgur.com/I64v5KT.png) is turned off in `App Service=>Configuration=>General Settings`. If yes, turn it `on`, save and deploy again

Comment: @JWave, Did it work or are you still getting error?

Comment: It was on, I tried disabling it and turning on again but no change unfortunately

Comment: Please add the error screenshot here, will check and try to help. Also create a new app service and try to deploy again

Comment: [Git error on deploy](https://imgur.com/jqohB9v)

Comment: Did you try to add setting `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM` to `true` in `WebApp=>Settings=>Configuration`

Comment: I had tried that earlier. I tried starting a new app and that is getting through deployment! woo! However I'm getting a 400 error on the webpage. Could that be to do with allowed hosts? I get the same error when I run it locally and  don't have the local IP in allowed_hosts. Should I have 'https://treebush.azurewebsites.net/'? replaced "ajhb" with "treebush" app

Comment: Yes, you need to add the URL to Allowed_Hosts.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for all your help, I've got up and running :)